# I am getting onFailure when I send a Base64 String to server

Tags: android, base64, okhttp

As the title says, I am encoding a Base64 String. I do it this way:

```
public String getStringFile2(File file){
    String retorno="";
    InputStream inputStream = null;//You can get an inputStream using any IO API
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        byte[] video = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        byte[] base64 = Base64.encode(video,Base64.NO_WRAP);
        String s = new String(base64, "UTF8");
        retorno=s;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.i("David", "FileNotFoundException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("David", "IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("David", retorno);
return retorno;
}
```

After that, I send it to server this way:

```
public void videoUploadTo()
{
    final OkHttpClient cliente=new OkHttpClient();
    File file=new File(vidPath);
    HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(getString(R.string.sendvideourl)).newBuilder();
    String video=getStringFile2(file);
    String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();
    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("operatingsystem", "Android")
            .addFormDataPart("mobilemodel",Utils.getDeviceName())
            .addFormDataPart("mobileversion",String.valueOf(Utils.getAndroidVersion()))
            .build();
    Request request=new Request.Builder()
            .post(requestBody)
            .addHeader("eid", String.valueOf(almacen.getEvento().getId()))
            .addHeader("token",almacen.getToken())
            .addHeader("video",video)
            .url(url)
            .build();
    cliente.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.i("David", "onFailure");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            Log.i("David", "onResponse");
        }
    });
}
```

(Yes, I need to send info in Headers)

Why it is failing? I think its not timeout because it does not takes too long to receive the answer.

Any help? Thanks.

EDIT: If i comment .addHeader("video",video) line I receive a 200...but I need to send that String.

Comment: You are encoding an empty `video` buffer. Further you should not mess around with utf-8 encoding too.

Comment: `IOException e` You are not logging -nor telling us- the value of `e.getMessage()`.

Comment: `I am getting onFailure .... ` That is your own message. You are throwing away the real message.

Comment: There is no message...

Comment: And also, video is not empty...it has content, but the encoded Base64 is a long succesions of AAAAAAA. How can I convert that file to Base64 properly...?

Comment: It has random content depending on the use of that allocated memory before. But you are not loading your file in that buffer.

Comment: Solved! You put me in the right path. Thanks @blackapps

Comment: You owe me to tell how you solved it i think.

Comment: This is the code that I used in the end: try {
                inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                int length = (int)file.length();
                byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
                int a=inputStream.read(bytes,0,length);
                retorno = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

Comment: `if (a!=length) {.. i do nothing.. i dont care.. this will not happen to me..}`